# Why are linear and spline term estimates so different?

Tags: regression, survival, interpretation, cox-model, splines

I am working on modelling in an epidemiological setting. I want to estimate the association between an exposure (air pollution) and two event outcomes. To achieve that, I am using a Cox PH model with time-varying exposure (I work with the `survival` package in R).

I defined two main models:

1. **Linear**: `coxph(Surv(time1, time2, event) ~ covariates + exposure)`
2. **Spline**:  `coxph(Surv(time1, time2, event) ~ covariates + pspline(exposure, df=4))`

The estimated associations for the **linear** model are displayed by 5-unit increase in the exposure:

- Outcome 1: HR= 1.21 (95% confidence intervals = 1.03-1.43)
- Outcome 2: HR= 1.22 (95% confidence intervals = 1.00-1.50)

The estimated association for the **spline** model are displayed below, using as reference the lowest value of the exposure (x in the graph).

[image]

I don't understand why despite having very similar HRs in the linear model, their curves are so different in the spline model. Especially, for outcome 1, I don't understand how the linear HR can be 1.22 when in the curve is mostly below 1.00 until the exposure is approximately 12 (x $\approx$ 12)

Code for HR spline plots (simplified and ispired by Terry Therneau [tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/splines.pdf)):

```
#DATA EXTRACTION
mod <- coxph(Surv(time1, time2, event) ~ covariates + pspline(exposure, df=4), data=df)
pmterm <- termplot(mod,terms = which(mod$pterms == 1),
                 se=TRUE, plot=FALSE)
dtplot<- list(pmterm = pmterm[["exposure"]], exposure = df$exposure)

 
#DATA FORMATTING
 centre <- with(dtplot$spline, y[x==min(x)])
 ytemp <- dtplot$spline$y + outer(dtplot$spline$se, c(0, -1.96, 1.96), '*')
 ytemp <- exp(ytemp - centre) #THIS LINE IS COMMENTED FOR LOG-HAZARD PLOT
 datspline <- data.frame(cbind(dtplot$spline$x,ytemp))
 datexp<- data.frame(dtplot$exp)
 names(dat)<-c("exp","HR","low","up")
 
#PLOTTING
 ggplot(datspline, aes(x = exp)) +
 geom_line(aes(y=HR)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=low, ymax=up),alpha = .1) +
 geom_histogram(aes(x=exp, y=10*(after_stat(density))), binwidth=1, 
        linewidth=0,colour="firebrick3",fill="firebrick3", alpha = 0.25, 
        data=datexp) + #GEOM_HISTOGRAM IS EXCLUDED FOR LOG-HAZARD PLOT
labs(title=paste0("outcome ",i), x = "exposure", y = "HR (95% CI)") + #y="log-hazard" FOR LOG-HAZARD PLOT
theme_classic() +
geom_hline(yintercept = 1, lty = 2) +  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,2.5)) #ylim=c(-0.5,0.5) FOR LOG-HAZARD PLOT
```

Comment: What's the distribution of exposure time? And how many events happen at high exposures?

Comment: What do you mean the distribution of exposure time? Regarding your second question, most of the events (approx. 70-80%) occur below 12 unit of exposure.

Comment: It would help if you could please edit the question to show the tabular reports for the two models. Something like `print(linearModel)` and `print(splineModel)`; see Section 5.5 of [Therneau and Grambsch](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842). Showing the code that produced the plots from the models would help, too. For comparison against a model linear in exposure, changing the y-axis of your plots to the log-hazard instead of the hazard ratio would be preferable.

Comment: Distribution of exposure time would be how many people had how much exposure.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'll update the question with some code. @EdM why do you think it's better to plot the log-hazards instead of the HR?

Comment: @jmarkov if you did the above plots for the linear model, on the log-hazard scale they would be straight lines. On the HR scale they would be exponentials. Maybe not a big difference with your fairly restricted range of HR values, but over time I've learned that it's usually much easier to think about things and do calculations in the log-hazard scales of the model coefficients and only change to HRs at the very end if ever.

Comment: I added code for plots and improved the plots with log-hazards and exposure distribution. Sorry, @EdM I haven't posted the `print()` yet as I would have to re-run the model which takes some time. Let me know if this gives enough info

Comment: @PeterFlom regarding the number of events by exposure units I have: for outcome 1 4600 cases for exposure <=10,  7450 for exposure <= 12 and 2000 above 12. For outcome 2 I have 3250 for exposure <=10, 5100 for exposure <=12 and 1200 above 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HR and log-hazard plots are dominated visually by the estimates at the extremes of `exposure`, where we now see that there are relatively fewer observations. Note how wide the confidence intervals are at those extremes.

In the linear model, you report HRs of 1.21 and 1.22 for a 5-unit increase in `exposure` for the two outcomes. In the log-hazard scale, those correspond to slopes of `log(1.21)/5` and `log(1.22)/5` per 1-unit increase of `exposure`, approximately 0.038 and 0.040, respectively. Try superimposing lines with those slopes on the spline fits in the log-hazard scales, passing through the corresponding origins on the `exposure` axis for 0 log hazard. Show the results on this page. I think you'll see that the spline fits aren't that far off from those linear fits overall, except at the extremes.

Applying the `print()` function to the models using `pspline()` will provide an output that evaluates whether the nonlinear terms add anything statistically significant beyond the linear terms. Whether any nonlinearity is substantively important depends on your understanding of the subject matter.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: @jmarkov for others who might visit this page, consider posting the spline-fit log-hazard plots with the superimposed linear approximations (maybe also with the code) as another answer here. It's OK to post an answer to your own question on this site.

Comment: I posted it, do you think it's clear enough?

Answer (score 2):

Following @EdM answer, I show that splines and linear estimated associations apparently looking very different, in fact, when displayed using the right transformation are similar.

Below you find the graph of the spline log-hazards (black line) and 95% confidence intervals (gray shades) for outcome 1 and 2. It is showed overimposed the blue line which consists of the beta estimated using the linear term.  I t is showed in the background the histogram of the exposure distribution (in red).

[image]

Code (in R) to compute model estimates and plot graphs for a single outcome (linear associations are computed for a 1 unit increment in exposure):

```
  #MODEL ESTIMATION

  #Spline model
  modspline <- coxph(Surv(time1, time2, event) ~ covariates + pspline(exposure, df=4),data=df)
  pmterm <- termplot(mod,terms = which(mod$pterms == 1),se=TRUE, plot=FALSE)
  splinest<- list(pmterm = pmterm[["exposure"]], exposure = df$exposure)

  #Linear model
  modlin <- coxph(Surv(time1, time2, event) ~ covariates + exposure,data=df)
  ind <- grep("cbpm25", names(coef(mod)))
  coef <- coef(mod)[ind]
  vcov <- vcov(mod)[ind,ind,drop=F]
  hrfit  <- exp(coef)
  hrlow  <- exp(coef - 1.96*sqrt(vcov))
  hrup <- exp(coef + 1.96*sqrt(vcov))
  cat(round(c(hrfit,hrlow,hrhigh))#display linear HR with 95%CI
  
  #FUNCTION TO COMPUTE INTERCEPT
  intercept<-function(x,y,slope){mean(y) - slope * mean(x)}


  #EXTRACT DATA FOR PLOT OF LOG-HAZARD

  #for spline (black curve and shaded grey area)
  centre <- with(splinest$spline, y[x==min(x)])
  ytemp <- splinest$spline$y + outer(splinest$spline$se, c(0, -1.96, 1.96), '*')
  dat <- data.frame(cbind(splinest$spline$x,ytemp))
  datexp<- data.frame(splinest$exposure)
  mexp<-mean(datexp$pm.exp)
  names(dat)<-c("exposure","loghazard","low","up")
    
  #for linear effect (blue line)
  inter<-intercept(x=mexp, y=0, slope=coef)
  
  #PLOT GRAPH
  ggplot(dat, aes(x = exposure)) +
    geom_line(aes(y=loghazard)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=low, ymax=up), alpha=0.2) +
    geom_histogram(aes(x=pm.exp, y=2*(after_stat(density))), binwidth=1, size=0,
                   colour="firebrick3", fill="firebrick3", alpha = 0.25, data=datexp) +
    geom_abline(intercept = inter, slope = coef, col="blue") +
    labs(title=paste0("outcome ",i), x = "exposure", y = "log-hazard") + theme_classic() +  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-0.5,0.7),
```

Comment: Looks good. Thanks. (+1)